# Python Logging getting error: Too many open files

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, python-3.5

My situation is, I have a configuration file that, obviously, is imported/called every time the system runs.

In my configuration file I have a dict with the logging's configurations and in the beginning of the program I get this configuration and do the logging.config.dictConfig() with the dict.

My system run in subprocess with at least 100 workers using the RQ. Sometimes, when the system is running, I keep getting the error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/manutencao/Heimdall/heimdall/worker.py", line 146, in heimdall_tradutor
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1279, in info
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1415, in _log
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1425, in handle
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1487, in callHandlers
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 855, in handle
File "/home/manutencao/Heimdall/heimdall/logger.py", line 28, in emit
File "/home/manutencao/Ratatosk/ratatosk/__init__.py", line 69, in __init__
File "/home/manutencao/Ratatosk/ratatosk/__init__.py", line 133, in get_logger
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/handlers.py", line 150, in __init__
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/handlers.py", line 57, in __init__
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1008, in __init__
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1037, in _open
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/home/manutencao/Ratatosk/ratatosk/JobRQ.log'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/manutencao/.virtualenvs/heimdall/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 588, in perform_job
File "/home/manutencao/.virtualenvs/heimdall/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 498, in perform
File "/home/manutencao/Heimdall/heimdall/worker.py", line 195, in heimdall_tradutor
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1314, in exception
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1308, in error
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1415, in _log
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1425, in handle
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1487, in callHandlers
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 855, in handle
File "/home/manutencao/Heimdall/heimdall/logger.py", line 28, in emit
File "/home/manutencao/Ratatosk/ratatosk/__init__.py", line 69, in __init__
File "/home/manutencao/Ratatosk/ratatosk/__init__.py", line 133, in get_logger
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/handlers.py", line 150, in __init__
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/handlers.py", line 57, in __init__
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1008, in __init__
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1037, in _open
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/home/manutencao/Ratatosk/ratatosk/JobRQ.log'
```

I have a custom logger handler:

```py
class RQHandler(logging.Handler):  # Inherit from logging.Handler
    def __init__(
        self, formatter=JSONFormatter(), level=logging.NOTSET,
        connection_pool=None
    ):
        # run the regular Handler __init__
        logging.Handler.__init__(self, level)
        self.formatter = formatter
        self.connection_pool = connection_pool

    def emit(self, record):
        # record.message is the log message
        ratatosk = Ratatosk(
            all_queues={'huginn_log': [1, 1]},
            debug=configuracoes['level_log'],
            REDIS_HOST=conf_redis['host'],
            REDIS_PORT=conf_redis['port'],
            REDIS_DB=conf_redis['db'],
            connection_pool=(
                self.connection_pool or conf_redis.get('connection_pool')
            )
        )
        ratatosk.enqueue(
            'huginn_log',
            'huginn.service.register_log',
            (self.format(record)),
        )
```

Basically, I just get the logger and add it to a RQ Queue.

I have read that this error is caused when you have too many handlers in the logging. Is that happening because I added the logging.config.dictConfig() in the beginning of my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It most likely means there is an error with an unclosed connection to Redis or file in the implementation of `RataTosk` (a socket counts as an open file in linux).  You can increase your file limits in linux if you are confident in the implementation:

```
ulimit -Hn
ulimit -Sn
# increase the fs.file-max in /etc/sysctl.conf to *2 of greater of the two
# restart the process hosting your python app
```

Comment: I don't think the `Ratatosk` is opening more than 1024 connection. It is just a manager for Redis, to enqueue a task. Is it possible that the Logging is opening the files and not closing them?

Comment: Well, your custom logger is creating a `RataTosk`, and nothing else.  So probably not.  The python/django logger works in production very well and with minimal fuss if you are using ordinary logging, logging to file or even sentry.

Comment: Also, to enqueue a task to redis, the RatoTask has to create a socket connection to Redis (usually over port 6379).

Comment: Yeah, that is it. I went back and checked the `Ratatosk` implementation. When it is instantiated, for some unknown reason, this lib creates logging with an handler RotatingFileHandler. Since I have around 120 worker, it was over the 1024 files open from the OS.
Thank you for you help, it save me many hours.